# Keeping only rows with highest amount value

Tags: sql, teradata-sql-assistant

I would like to know how to select the users having greatest amount and their corresponding model.For each user I have many emails. 
The dataset looks like

```
User Email Model Amount
1    name1  1      -2000
1    name11 1      -300
1    name12 3      -7000
42   name2  13     -3200
42   name21 1      -3520
...
```

I would need to keep only rows having (user email model and amount) having the greater amount. Since the value is negative, I would need to keep the slowest value (e.g. -7000 for user 1).

How could I do it in SQL Teradata Assistant?

Comment: What results do you want?  One row per model or per user?  And the negative values make the question really confusing.  `-7000` is the SMALLEST amount, not the GREATEST amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you db allow join  on subquery

```
select t.User, m.Email, m.Model, m.Amount
gtom my_table m
inner join   (
    select user, max(amount) max_amount
    from my_table 
    group by user
) t on t.user = m.user
    and t.max_amount  = m.amount
```

Comment: Hi scaisEdge. I think you answer could work. However I am having some issues as both users and amounts comes from table which joins another one (email). How could Inselect the user of max amount?

Comment: explain better  ..  you have two jser with the same max(amount)  ??    so what ypour .. expected  result   ..   ..eventually update your question and add  clear data sample and the related  expected  result

Comment: I opened a new question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61823394/calculate-variable-of-max-amount-in-a-group?noredirect=1#comment109351137_61823394

Answer (score 1):

In Teradata, this would typically be done using `qualify`.  If you want one row per user with the smallest amount:

```
select t.*
from t
qualify row_number() over (partition by user order by amount) = 1;
```

If you wanted one row per user, you would just change the `partition by`.  If you wanted the biggest value rather than the smallest, you would add `desc` to the `order by`.