# Calculate variable of max amount in a group

Tags: sql, teradata-sql-assistant

I have difficulties in doing the following exercise. I would need to find how frequent is that an `id` is not the `max_id` in the group with the most `amount`. This should be done considering groups that contain at least two different people.
Data comes from two different tables: `max_id` comes from table1 (I will call it `a`)as well as `user` and `amount`; `id` comes from table2 (`b`) as well as group. 
From the text above, the conditions should be

```
(1) a.id<>b.max_id /* is not */
(2) people in group >=2
(3) a.id<> id of max amount
```

The dataset looks like

(a)

```
max_id  user  amount
```

(b)

```
group email
```

From a previous exercise, I had to compute distinct people as follows:

```
sel a.distinct users
a.max_id
b.id
from table1 as a
inner join table2 as b
on b.id=a.max_id

where
b.max_id is not null
and b.time is null
```

No information from amount was required in the exercise above. This is the main difference between the two exercises, but the structure and fields are quite similar.
Now, I would need to edit the code above in order to find how frequent is that an `id` is not the `max_id` in the group with the most `amount`. This makes sense only if groups have at least two different persons/users. 
I think I will need to join tables to get the id of max amount in a group and count people in a group, but I do not know how to do it. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Data sample

```
max_id  user  amount id group email
12       1    -2000  12 house email1
312      1      0    54 work  email1
11       32    -213  11 house email32
41       13    -43   78 work  email13
312      53    -650  34 work  email53
1        67    -532  43 defense email67
64       76   -9650  98 work  email76
```

For my understanding, what the exercise asks and based on the code above, I should find values for `id<>max_id` and having more than `2 users` in a `group` (i.e. house, work, defence). 
Then, what I would need to select is `id <> id of max amount`.

I hope this it can be a bit more clear.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: i have posted  an aswer  based on your previos question  hope is useful

Comment: thank you @scaisEdge. I just finished to update the question. I do not know if this may cause a change in your answer. I have tried to explains as well as possible the problem. Thank you for your help.

Comment: you question seem not related  to my answer  so past some minutes i delete the answer  ..  anyway your question is not clear  ..  try add  also a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: @sciasEdge I updated the question. I hope it can be clearer. I have not understood the part of group and how to compute the max neither

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming yoy have a query as

```
select t.User, m.Email, m.Model, m.Amount
from my_table m
inner join   (
    select user, max(amount) max_amount
    from my_table 
    group by user
) t on t.user = m.user
    and t.max_amount  = m.amount
```

you can obatin the max di for each amoun using

```
select max(id), Amount
from (

    select m.id, t.User, m.Email, m.Model, m.Amount
    from my_table m
    inner join   (
        select user, max(amount) max_amount
        from my_table 
        group by user
    ) t on t.user = m.user
        and t.max_amount  = m.amount
) k
```

and you should obtain the valud of id that are not equal to max id as

```
select mm.id, t.User, mm.Email, mm.Model, mm.Amount
    from my_table mm
    inner join   (
        select user, max(amount) max_amount
        from my_table 
        group by user
    ) t on t.user = m.user
        and t.max_amount  = m.amount
inner join  (
    select max(k.id) max_id, k.Amount
    from (

        select m.id, t.User, m.Email, m.Model, m.Amount
        from my_table m
        inner join   (
            select user, max(amount) max_amount
            from my_table 
            group by user
        ) t on t.user = m.user
            and t.max_amount  = m.amount
    ) k

    ) kk ON kk.max_id <> mm.id
```

and based on your last sample the query should  be

```
select m.*
from my_table
inner join  (
    select my_groups, count(distinct user)
    from my_table 
    group by my_groups
    having count(distinct user) >2
) t on t.my_group = m.my_group 
    and m.max_id <> m.id
```

PS  group is a reserved  word so i use my_groups for the column name

Comment: I updated the question. I hope it can be clearer. Thank you for your help

Comment: Thank you so much for updating the answer based on my sample data. Just one question: where I select from there the id of max amount, i.e. `a.id<> id of max amount` ?

Comment: in your sample the max_id is a column value ..  so you comment si not clear to  me.. what do you mean ..  ( in my previous code sample the max_id became from subquery)